# store several plots in a list to access them later

Tags: python, list, matplotlib, vtk

I create in my python file several plots with matplotlib.
I want to access them later and plot them on a VTK object. I tried to create a list and just append them as plot objects.

```
for i in range(len(x)):
    ax = plt.subplot(111, projection='polar')
    plt.legend()
    plot_l.append(plt.show())
```

But this does not work quite well.
I also tried with `plt.savefig('somewhere/folder')` and reload them out of the file.

But this does not meet me needs, because I have a huge amount of plots I want to have the plots just in the file.

How do I store several plots as `png` to access them later, like `plot_l[10]`?
Or is there a better alternative?

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try saving your `ax` object, instead.

```
import pickle

# [...your plotting code here...]

pickle.dump(ax, file('filename', 'w'))
```

And this is how you would load it next time you need it:

```
ax = pickle.load(file('filename'))
```

In your specific case, you might prefer to put this inside a loop and have `filename` depend on the looping index, etc.

And finally, you might want to try the same with a list object, to keep everything in one file, as you indicated.